# Initialising dictionary of multiple types

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to initialise an empty dictionary, which has multiple entries of different types. For example:

```
var dictionary = ["imageFile": PFFile, "title": String, "likes": Int]
```

How do i do this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare a heterogenous dictionary by setting the variable type to `[String:Any]`, or `[String:AnyObject]`, depending on what kind of data you want to place in there.

e.g.

```
let anyDictionary: [String:Any] = [...]
let anyObjectDictionary: [String:AnyObject] = [...]
```

Two notes, though:

1. use `let` as much as possible, `var` only if you don't have other alternative
2. heterogenous dictionaries increase the complexity of your code, mainly because you loose the type safety, I'd recommend having a model `struct`/`class` for that dictionary